# How to specify package version with `conda skeleton pypi` command?

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I would like to make a conda package from the [0.0.8 version of the pipy scikit-fmm package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-fmm/0.0.8).

To achieve this, I should be able to use the `conda skeleton pypi` command as stated in [the doc](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/build_tutorials/pkgs.html#build-a-simple-package-with-conda-skeleton-pypi).

[The help of the command](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/commands/build/conda-skeleton-pypi.html) indicates that it is possible to specify a particular version with the `--version`.
So I try to execute the command below...

```
conda skeleton pypi --version 0.0.8 scikit-fmm
```

...which results in the following output:

```
Warning, the following versions were found for scikit-fmm
0.0.1
0.0.2
0.0.3
0.0.4
0.0.5
0.0.6
0.0.7
0.0.8
0.0.9
Using 0.0.9
Use --version to specify a different version.
Using url https://pypi.python.org/packages/0b/fd/2bb33ca6114c2e8c76f19768eb68d0fcc10ec7aba854671d9c9448626da6/scikit-fmm-0.0.9.tar.gz (404 KB) for scikit-fmm.
Downloading scikit-fmm
...
```

So my questions are: How does this `--version` option work? What am I doing wrong? How to actually specify the version?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in the current 2.0.7 release of conda-build.  Please update, and report back if this is still an issue.

Comment: Thanks, how do I tell what python version is for my conda? I see 4.6.7 if I run `conda -V`